# Having trouble showing custom view to the application

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: This is my layout. Please check this image out]

Hi, so the circled area is the custom view. and Right now I'm using relative layout and I added the custom view to the activity_main like this:

```
<letusdraw.cView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radiogroup"  /// to the left of the radio group in the image
    android:layout_above="@+id/textviewsBelow"/> /// above the texts "x: ...y:..."
```

Now when I try to run my code on emulator, I get an error on Logcat saying the second line of the below code is buggy and "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() on a null object reference"

```
    RadioGroup radio = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    int currentCheck = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Now I tried everything to find what the error is and as a last resort commented out the custom view I added in activity_main (the first code block) and it doesn't throw an error. So I'm guessing the custom view is the problem. What could the error be? Is it because my custom view is blocking the radio group? If my layout is the problem, what layout would you use? and is there any way to keep the relative layout I'm using and fix this issue?

Comment: Not enough source code, please add more

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using "group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();" without intializing "group".

try this.

```
RadioGroup group = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
int currentCheck = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```